# Different note lengths on guitar pro 6

Tags: guitar-pro

How can I have a rest above a note in guitar pro 6. For a classical guitar song I need the bass note a different length to the melody so I need to know how to split them. the picture explains what I want to be able to do.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use the "Voices" feature. Guitar Pro allows up to 4 voices on a single track, and each voice has it's own beat count and can have notes that have different lengths.

By default, you are writing notes on the first voice, you can change the current voice, using those buttons under the tab, between the tab and the tracks : 
[image: Voices]

When a voice is selected the notes of the other voices are greyed out, like on your example.
The last button allows you to display "correctly" all the notes of all the voices.

Arobas published a [tutorial video](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/200633951-Video-GP6-editing-Multiple-voice-edition) if you need more information.